# Cómo buscar en un many to many field en django?

Tags: django

Mi modelo Capacitacion tiene un atributo "cargos" ( `cargos = models.ManyToManyField(Cargo, verbose_name="cargos")` ), y el modelo Persona tiene el atributo "cargo".

Quiero buscar todas las Capacitaciones programadas al cargo de esa persona

Para saber si estoy en lo correcto:

```
persona_r = Persona.objects.get(id=idPersona)
capacitaciones_r = Capacitacion.objects.filter(cargos__id=persona_r.cargo)
```

Comment: Agrega el código donde defines tus modelos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener las capacitaciones relacionados a un cargo seria:

```
persona_r = Persona.objects.get(id=idPersona)
capacitaciones = persona_r.cargo.capacitacion_set.all()
```

Puedes ver la [documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships)